# Some questions with NetFSMountURLAsync?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am working on a OS X app which mount server volumes through `NetFSMountURLAsync`. And now I have many questions.

- When I successfully mounting a volume from server and I want to check
  if the share always available. Then I close the share, but I can
  still check it's online through `NSFileManager`'s `mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys: options:`. Afterwards I use `getResourceValue: forKey: error:` to retrieve volumename by `NSURLVolumeNameKey` so I can get offline status if there is not volume name exists, but it is still not quick enough. How to get status change immediately?
- When I just use `NetFSMountURLAsync` to mount and unmount a volume repeatly, I found the memory keep increasing even I stop any operations it still keep high memory and not release. I use ARC and no other operations. At the same time, `NetAuthSysAgent`'s memory also keep increasing, Any ideas?
- And last when it takes long time to mount I use `NetFSMountURLCancel` to cancel a mount, but sometimes it just hang there and do not terminate. How's that happens?
- Is there any mount option key for automount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time working with this project, I had have to give up. There is no other way to get status change quickly as I know. Maybe can use Instruments to check memory leak. Importantly take carefully checking retain-cycle in the block.